# How do I do a patch request using HttpClient in dotnet core?

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, http-patch

I am trying to create a `Patch` request with the`HttpClient` in dotnet core. I have found the other methods,

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.GetAsync("/posts");
    client.PostAsync("/posts", ...);
    client.PutAsync("/posts", ...);
    client.DeleteAsync("/posts");
}
```

but can't seem to find the `Patch` option. Is it possible to do a `Patch` request with the `HttpClient`? If so, can someone show me an example how to do it?

Comment: use a `HttpRequestMessage`

Comment: Thanks @DanielA.White you got me on my way!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of Feb 2022
[image: Update 2022]

###Original Answer###

As of .Net Core 2.1, the `PatchAsync()` is now available for `HttpClient`

[image: Snapshot for applies to]

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.patchasync

Comment: PatchAsync exist in .Net Standard 2.1 only.

Answer (score 33):

Thanks to Daniel A. White's comment, I got the following working.

```cs
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{       
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("PATCH"), "your-api-endpoint");

    try
    {
        response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException ex)
    {
        // Failed
    }
}
```

EDIT: For .NET (Core) see [@LxL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57779194/951001) answer.

Comment: where do you add the body?

Comment: @DanielGatti is right. What are you sending as the body for your PATCH? What I did was add it to the object. request.Content = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "applicantion/json");

Comment: see my response on how to add body

Comment: I would suggest using `HttpMethod.Patch` rather than `"PATCH"`.

Comment: Updated my answer and changed the accepted answer!

Answer (score 12):

HttpClient does not have patch out of the box.
Simply do something like this:

```
// more things here
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = hostUri;
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", base64Credentials);
    var method = "PATCH";
    var httpVerb = new HttpMethod(method);
    var httpRequestMessage =
        new HttpRequestMessage(httpVerb, path)
        {
            Content = stringContent
        };
    try
    {
        var response = await client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var responseCode = response.StatusCode;
            var responseJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            throw new MyCustomException($"Unexpected http response {responseCode}: {responseJson}");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        throw new MyCustomException($"Error patching {stringContent} in {path}", exception);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Feb 2024, You can just specify Method = Patch.

```
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
        {
            RequestUri = new Uri(url),
            Method = HttpMethod.Patch,
            Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(requestData)
        };

        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

Send request data as Dictionary<string, string>.